# DeploymentException with WebSockets, TyrusServer

Tags: java, scala, websocket, tyrus

```
set 26, 2014 5:13:00 PM org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint callMethod
INFO: Exception thrown from onError method public void main.scala.SocksEndpoint2.onError(javax.websocket.Session,java.lang.Throwable).
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Component provider threw exception when providing instance of class main.scala.SocksEndpoint2.
```

What Can cause this? I'm using an endpoint almost completely empty:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocks")
class SocksEndpoint2(system: ActorSystem) {

  @OnMessage
  def onMessage(mess: String, session: Session) {

  }
  @OnClose
  def onClose(session: Session) {

  }

  @OnError
  def onError(session: Session , t: Throwable) {

  }
}
```

and sending via javascript

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8025/websocks")
exampleSocket.send("{}")
```

and it returns the error above.

Comment: you clearly have issues with instantiation of SocksEndpoint2 class. It must be public and must have constructor with zero parameters - to be able to do something like "Class.forName(...).newInstance()".

Comment: He could also handle the instantiation himself with a `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` and its `getInstance()` call

Comment: @PavelBucek if you add your comment as answer I'll mark it right :)

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint class must be public;

you clearly have issues with instantiation of `SocksEndpoint2` class. It must be public and must have constructor with zero parameters - to be able to do something like `Class.forName(...).newInstance()`.